# Does the lumen value of a light bulb take into account the inverse square law and volume of a room?

Tags: everyday-life, lightning, light-emitting-diodes

For example, I am trying to calculate the number of 800lm light bulbs required to light a 16sq meter bed room with a 2.5m celling that doubles as a study. Assuming 75 lux is required, this converts to 1200 lumens. Below are what I have calculated so far:

Let x be the number of light bulbs required:

1/2.5^2 * 800lm x = 1200lm
x = 9.375

Which seems quite unreasonable... How would anyone need 9 bulbs in a room? Where is the error here? Do I not need to consider the inverse square law?

Comment: The inverse square law is exactly why they make table lamps.

Comment: Are you assuming the light is absorbed the first time it hits a surface?  The light reflection from white ceiling, light floors, non-black furniture, is significant.   Mirrors are good for conserving  illumination energy, too.

Comment: @safesphere yes that is true, but this is a question I'm trying to calculate. What did I do wrong in the calculations?

Comment: @Whit3rd Yes I am excluding all of those variables.

Comment: I didn't check the details of your calculation, but it sounds very reasonable to me that you'd need ten 800-lumen bulbs at the ceiling to create the intensity of a table lamp on the surface of your desk. I have four 800-lumen bulbs on my ceiling and the light is a bit dim. Note that the human busion is logarithmic. If you double the intensity, you don't see it doubled. You see it only very slightly increased.

Comment: If you have a white ceiling or a reflective light fixture, then your result should be divided by 2. Also note that the lumen values on bulb packaging are exaggerated for marketing. I've tried many bulbs and often those marked 800 are dimmer than others marked 500. Today higher intensity LED bulbs become cheap. 800 is rather low for a real LED bulb. I'd go for those marked over 1000 lumens. (I prefer the 2700K color, but it's just a personal taste.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are living with rooms that you describe then the simplest way to do the calculation is to work out the luminous flux (lumens) by multiplying the illuminance (lux) that you require by the base area of the room (metre$^2$).

So in your case you have evaluated the luminous flux that you require as $16\times 75 = 1200 \, \rm lm$.

Now divide this value by the luminous flux emitted by one bulb and a value of $\frac {1200}{800}= 1.5$ which you might consider more reasonable.

But as you know nothing in real life is that easy although if you double the number of lamps you will probably find the light levels in your room adequate except perhaps at your desk?

Now to get a better estimate you ought to look first at the level of illuminance that you require?
Here is a typical table with the values either at floor level eg for a corridor or at $0.75 \,\rm m$ above floor level for a study.

[image]

The rule of thumb for conversion between lumens and watts for different types of bulbs are shown in the table below.

[image]

The type of lamp used is obviously important but so is the way the lamp emits light.
An incandescent bulb distributes light in almost all directions whereas an LED tends to be very directional with a "beam angle" given in the specifications.
The room that you are in will also affect things not just due to its size but also due to the surface reflectance of the ceiling, walls, and floor which is encompassed in an average room reflectance factor called the luminaire utilisation factor ($U$) and there is also the ageing of the bulb and the bulb getting dirty with time factors which need to be taken into consideration - the maintenance factor ($M$).

So with next degree of sophistication the total number of lumens you need is $\dfrac{EA}{UM}$ where $E$ is the required illuminance (lus) and $A$ is the area (m$^2$).

Using [The Installer's Guide to Lighting Design](http://www.cibse.org/getmedia/0276ac78-dc41-4694-9378-8f984ef924f2/GPG300-The-Installers-Guide-to-Lighting-Design.pdf.aspx) I estimated a value of $U=0.4$ and $M=0.8$ for your room which gave a value of approximately $3800 \,\rm lm$ for an illuminance of $75\,\rm lx$ and a much higher value of $25,000 \,\rm lm$ if the illuminance is $500\,\rm lx$.
Perhaps a suitably positioned, reasonably high powered, medium beam angle LED will do the trick?

One of the comments summed it up very well -"The inverse square law is exactly why they make table lamps".
You will note that the inverse square law is not used directly in any of the calculations because you are dealing with reflected light as well as direct light.

Comment: Your calculation assumes 100% reflective walls and ceiling. In reality it is less than 100%, so 1.5 bulbs may be a bit low estimate.

Comment: @safesphere I did point out that my first estimate was just that and having twice the number might be closer to what is required. I then made what was perhaps a better estimate.

Comment: Yes, I see, 5 bulbs. Makes sense as roughly a half of the OP's number due to the ceiling reflections and such. I have four 800 LEDs in my living room and it's OK, but not enough for a prolonged work (I suspect these LEDs are not truly 800 as claimed). So in my office I have a 6000-lumen floor lamp pointed at the white vaulted ceiling. Much better :)

Answer (score 1):

Lumen is a different energy unit concerned with the light emission,  and can be [converted to watts](http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/light/lumen-to-watt-calculator.htm) (see the table).  It knows nothing about the dimensions it will radiate into. Different technologies will give light more efficiently in energy consumption , that is all.

If you needed 100 watt incandescent to light up a room, you can do it cheeply with  LED for 25 watts, that is all. How many light bulbs one needs to illuminate a room will depend not only on the dimensions but also on the colors and furnishings, and has to be gauged by experience. A 100 watt incandescent is efficient in a 4mx4mx3 room, so 1500 lumen should do it.

(Lux is a unit of one lumen per unit area, and yes, due to the 1/r^2 dispersion the value falls the further away.So if you have to calculate for the distance from the light source to have any meaning. At 3 meters a 1500 lumen source has to be divided by the area of the sphere at 3 meters to find the lux about 15 lux. I suppose the unit was chosen so the 1 lux was adequate illumination, whence did you get the 75? )

Comment: On a website it said " Rooms more intensive reading or study need to be better lit, with a lumens requirement of around 55 – 110 per square metre." so I took 75 lux as the optimum value. Assuming 75 lux would be required to light the room, how many 800 lumens bulb would I need?

Comment: Example 3 meters away from light source. A 1500 lumen divided by aproximate spherical area( 4*pi*3*3 )~100, there are 15 lumen per meter square (i.. lux's). At 1 meters away there are  ~150 lux. So it depends where you sit with respect to the light.1 bulb of 800 would give ~70 luxes at 1 meter. At three meters from the source  you would need about   9 800 lumen . That is why we have table lamps and desk lamps.